# Is there a conceptual proof that $A_n$ is simple for $n \ge 5$, or that it is the only nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, intuition, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

All the proofs I’ve seen of this are very combinatorial and at least for me not very memorable. Is there a cleaner or more conceptual proof? For instance, I wondered if representation theory might yield something easier. $S_n$ is such a ubiquitous group, that I imagine that looking at an appropriate action and employing techniques from the category in which the action lives, we might find a cleaner proof.

Comment: If you are familiar with the proof of the simplicity of $PSL_n(\Bbb{F}_q)$ there is a parallel. This is an exercise in e.g. Alperin & Bell. My estimate is that the overall structure of that proof of the simplicity of $A_n$ is more complicated than the ones you have seen. In theory you could also use the full character table of $S_n$ or $A_n$ to check that no non-trivial normal subgroups are there, but the same remark applies.

Comment: But, I'm not an expert on this. I do think that if a simpler proof existed, one of the books we both have read, would have it.

Comment: See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15773/simplicity-of-a-n) for several elegant proofs, and the linked proofs from Conrad's text.

Comment: Concerning the title: once we know that $A_n$ is simple, the second claim is trivial, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743387/show-that-a-n-is-the-only-non-trivial-normal-subgroup-of-s-n-for-n-geq-5?rq=1).